# Android in app purchase: BillingClient: getPurchase() failed. Response code: 3

Tags: android, android-inapp-purchase

I'm implementing Android in app purchases, with BillingClient api.

I successfully set up billing client, like this:

```
   billingClient = BillingClient.newBuilder(this)
        .enablePendingPurchases()
        .setListener(this).build()
```

And I implement the code I want to make the in app purchase, which in my case is a subscription.

My issue is as follows, I need to check (periodicly) if the user still has an active subscription, or if they canceled it. From what I read, I can do a call of the method, queryPurchases(PRODUCT_ID). I am doing this as follows:

```
 override fun onBillingSetupFinished(billingResult: BillingResult?) {
            if (billingResult != null) {

                if (billingResult.responseCode == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK){

                    // The BillingClient is ready. You can query purchases here.

                    Log.d(TAG_PURCHASES_ACTIVITY, "BillingClient ready and connected")

                    billingClient.queryPurchases(MONTHLY_AGENT_SUBSCRIPTION_PRODUCT_ID)

                }

                else{
                    Log.d(TAG_PURCHASES_ACTIVITY, "BillingClient ERROR: ${billingResult.responseCode}")
                }



            }
        }
```

However, I get this message in the console:

```
W/BillingClient: getPurchase() failed. Response code: 3
```

Now after researching, many have said that this is coming from old phones, with older versions of google play services. But I am using new phone (Pixel 3a), which is up to date. This phone also has the google account registered in the google play console for testing.

Why I am getting this message?

Also, is this really the correct way to check if the subscription is still active?

I've tried for ages to find this solution, thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was making a mistake, passing the product id as a parameter to the query request.
This is what I needed to do:

`var list = billingClient.queryPurchases(SkuType.SUBS)`

Comment: But this gives me a list of all the purchases of a particular product_id. How to get only one product with specific "order id", help me out